# Importing DEM on MAPublisher?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, mapinfo

We exported DEM, point, line and polygon data as .mdb or .gdb formats from ArcGIS. When we import these data to MapInfo, present database and when choosing the data from feature class there is only the point, line and polygon data shown, but there is no DEM data. I could try to import the DEM in raster format (.tiff or .bmp) but I believe that the image will get spoiled.

Is there any other way to import a DEM on MAPublisher?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Why do you say your "image will get spoiled"?  I would expect that an export to TIFF should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **[list of supported formats](http://www.avenza.com/mapublisher/features/supported-formats)** for MAPublisher.

The image formats which are supported are:  *.png, *.jpg, *.tif, *.gif,
*.jp2, *.psd, *.pdd, *.bmp. However, there is a note which states:

> Only TIFF, JPG, and PNG are supported in Export Image.

Though I suspect these exports are not georeferenced.

Comment: If this post answered your question, please accept it as per our [help page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).